# uber rideRequest deeplink not setting dropoff in app

Tags: android, uber-api, deeplink

I try to launch an Uber app intent from my android app using the folowing :

```
Activity_launch_request intent:Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=uber://?action=setPickup&client_id=<MY_ID_HERE>&pickup=my_location&pickup[nickname]=pickupNicknameTest&dropoff[latitude]=50.464521084216&dropoff[longitude]=4.8633537143047&dropoff[nickname]=dropoffNicknameTest }
```

The Uber app opens but there is no dropoff point set (it open the map, and a field "where do you want to go ?" on which i can click to set my destination). Am i missing something in the deeplink request ?
I tried to replace the "." by "," in the latitude and longitude value as i seen in another post but no success.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

From your example, it is not clear what parameter "pickup=my_location" looks like. You need to set pickup[latitude] and pickup[longitude] so your deep link should look like :

*uber://?client_id=&action=setPickup&pickup[latitude]=37.775818&pickup[longitude]=-122.418028&pickup[nickname]=UberHQ&pickup[formatted_address]=1455%20Market%20St%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094103&dropoff[latitude]=37.802374&dropoff[longitude]=-122.405818&dropoff[nickname]=Coit%20Tower&dropoff[formatted_address]=1%20Telegraph%20Hill%20Blvd%2C%20San%20Francisco%2C%20CA%2094133&product_id=a1111c8c-c720-46c3-8534-2fcdd730040d&link_text=View%20team%20roster&partner_deeplink=partner%3A%2F%2Fteam%2F9383*

I suggest to use deeplink [generator.](https://developer.uber.com/products/ride-requests-deeplink) Otherwise, you need to make sure that URL Encoding Parameter values used in linking must be fully [URL-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

For more information about deeplinks please check DeepLink [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/introduction).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I can see this in the doc :

"You can set the pickup location to be the user’s current location by setting pickup to my_location. With that, you don’t need to provide latitude/longitude query parameters."

( https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/deep-links/introduction#notes )

I made differents tries, and it seems that if the pickup point is not in a supported area, it will not set the dropoff either. But if i set the pickup point at uberHQ it works.